# Consume API layer service method from Projects Controller layer with Interface in Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, model-view-controller

I tried to call API layers  "MenuService.cs" from  "GetMenuService()" method from to Projects Controller layer. My structure is like this:

```
------API START------

-----Services
---MenuService.cs
   |
   GetMenuService()
                  {
               ... 
  . ...   some code 
                  }

------API END--------
------
------
-----
-------MyProject-----------
-----Controllers
---MyHomeController.cs
        var comingValue = _menuservice.GetMenuService();
```

But I have this error :

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyProjectSolution.MODEL.ServiceContracts.IMenuService' while attempting to activate 'MyProjectSolution.MyProject.Controllers.MyHomeController'.

Comment: DI container has no knowledge of how to resolve `IMenuService` (probably because it wasn't registered)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do the service registration in `ConfigureServices()` method inside `Startup.cs`

Eg:

```
services.AddScoped<IMenuService, MenuService>();
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: MenuService.cs just in API project, not MyProject. Should I  use like this import from api project to Myproject ; "using  MyProjectSolution.API.Services;"